# Which of the following is a secondary alkyl halide

Tags: organic-chemistry

a $\ce{(CH3)2CHCH2CCl(CH3)2}$

b $\ce{(CH3)2CHCHClCH3}$

c $\ce{(CH3)2CClCH3}$

d $\ce{(CH3)2CHCH2Cl}$

This is just to check that I'm understanding the material correctly.

I'm thinking it's c because when drawing the line structure the alpha carbon is connected to two other carbons.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you're wrong: b is the secondary alkyl halide. c (as well as a) is the tertiary alkyl halide, and d is the primary one.

Comment: B is connected to one CH3 groups as well as a CH meaning it's connected to three carbons making it secondary, but C is set up the same way.

Comment: In b the carbon atom to which $\ce{Cl}$ is attached is indeed connected with $\ce{CH3}$ on the one side and $\ce{CH}$ (more precisely, $\ce{(CH3)2CH}$ on the other side. But this means that this carbon atom is connected to just two other $\ce{C}$ atoms. Where did you get 3?

Answer (score 1):

Well, no. Here is the [quote from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloalkane#Classes_of_haloalkanes):

> From the structural perspective, haloalkanes can be classified
>   according to the connectivity of the carbon atom to which the halogen
>   is attached. In primary (1°) haloalkanes, the carbon that carries the
>   halogen atom is only attached to one other alkyl group. An example is
>   chloroethane ($\ce{CH3CH2Cl}$). In secondary (2°) haloalkanes, the carbon
>   that carries the halogen atom has two $\ce{C–C}$ bonds. In tertiary (3°)
>   haloalkanes, the carbon that carries the halogen atom has three $\ce{C–C}$ 
>   bonds.

So, the presence of $\ce{CH2Cl}$, $\ce{CHCl}$, and $\ce{CCl}$ are the indicators of primary, secondary, and tertiary haloalkane respectively.

Here is b with the $\ce{C}$ atom to which $\ce{Cl}$ is attached as well as its two $\ce{C–C}$ bonds highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was drawing C wrong which is why I was seeing it as a secondary and not a tertiary.